# Master page in Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

We have to migrate our sharepoint pages and other stuffs from classic mode to modern UI. We have master page perfectly in classic mode.

Is it possible to create master page in Modern UI?
if yes, could you please suggest the best option?

thanks

Comment: To whoever flagged this question as too broad: how come a question "Is it possible?" with 2 possible answers of "Yes" or "No" is too broad?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible, and not supported.

Please see the section [What's not supported on "modern" team sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#whats-not-supported-on-modern-team-sites) in Microsofts official customization guidelines for Modern experience